# How to add system tray in new panel?

Tags: unity, lubuntu, power-management, battery, indicator

Linux noob here. I was customizing my desktop panels.
I don't know how to add the 'system tray' panel applet(that is the one with the battery indicator which looks like this[image] ;I'm not referring to[image: the battery indicator applet that looks like those green bars in the picture.]the battery indicator applet that looks like those green bars in the picture.). My pc runs lubuntu 18.04.4 lts.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I believe you add 'Indicator Applets' to the panel, then modify the settings. Some indicators can only show on a single panel I believe, so if you have two panels you can have them show on one panel, but not the other.  (sorry I don't have battery indicators on my desktop to confirm if that relates to battery).  I don't know why you tagged *Unity* though (a different desktop to LXDE used by Lubuntu 18.04 LTS).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for adding Unity in there. But are you sure that this is gonna work? Cause before adding to the new panel, I gotta remove it from the old one. But if it does not show up in the new one, then I'm done for good. I'll see if anyone answers the question. If no one does, then I'll try what you said. Thank you guiverc.

Comment: I had a brief look at this and found variation of panel configs; on x86 installs the panel config was `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel` but on x86_64 it was `~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel` but `xfce4-power-manager` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xfce4-power-manager) had already ported to GTK3, so it's no longer *native* on LXDE/18.04 (LXDE is GTK2). I don't know your architecture, but using 18.04 makes me think x86 (it was last of LXDE/gtk2 so was missing the upgrade path thus made more sense for x86/32bit users. I wasn't successful in a brief play sorry.